# GMail API: threads().list with pageToken misses some threads in the results

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm trying to get the list of threads from my mailbox marked with label. Example of code on Python (based on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)

```
try:
    response = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me', labelIds='Label_1').execute()
    if 'threads' in response:
        threads.extend(response['threads'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
        page_token = response['nextPageToken']
        response = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me', labelIds='Label_1', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        threads.extend(response['threads'])

except errors.HttpError, error:
    logging.error('ERROR: page_token ' + page_token + ' ' + str(error))

print len(threads)
threads = set([x.get('id') for x in threads])  #exclude threads with the same id
print len(threads)
```

The output is:

```
2264  
1862
```

While in my mail box I see 2644 emails with label 'Label_1'.
Can you please help me out for this problem?

Comment: Did you try in API explorer https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list to check whether you are getting 2644 emails in response or not?

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3735  :(

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, and was able to solve it by switching the order of the 'if' and 'while' statements, like so:

```
response = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me', labelIds='Label_1').execute()

while 'nextPageToken' in response:
    page_token = response['nextPageToken']
    response = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me', labelIds='Label_1', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    threads.extend(response['threads'])
if 'threads' in response:
    threads.extend(response['threads'])
```

This is because the code that you (and Google's API documentation!) used doesn't actually return the last page of results. It says to get the first page of results, then move on if there are no threads in it, until there's no 'nextPageToken' on the current page. The fix I suggested cycles through all the pages with a 'nextPageToken' first, then does one more if it contains any threads. Incidentally, this also handles the case where there is only one page of results to begin with (since the 'while' loop won't be executed).

That worked for me. Hope it works for you.